# Wrong time from database in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There is some model TimeCorrection in my Rails application. It has got 3 fields: start_time, end_time and value. I've got 1 record in the database with values:

```
start_time: 2014-01-10 06:58:57.507512
end_time: 2014-01-10 06:58:58.507532
value: 10
```

I need to show it in JSON format:

```
tc = TimeCorrection.first
render json: [tc.start_time, tc.end_time]
```

But I've got the following output:

```
[
    "2000-01-01T06:58:57Z",
    "2000-01-01T06:58:58Z"
]
```

Time is incorrect as you can see. What I do wrong? How can I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: please insert this `logger.debug tc.inspect` right after the `tc = TimeCorrection.first` and give its output

Comment: What is the column type in the database and where did you copy that example data from?